# Create vector p for a sparse Matrix from a matrix of positions

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Let's say I want to create a sparse matrix `SMatrix` where all non-zero values are 1.
I already have a matrix of `positions`, where column 1 stores row index and column 2 stores  col index:

```
vec1 <- c(10,1)
vec2 <- c(12,1)
vec3 <- c(2,3)

positions <- matrix(c(vec1, vec2, vec3),
                    ncol=2,
                    dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", "col")),
                    byrow = T)
positions
     row col
[1,]  10   1
[2,]  12   1
[3,]   2   3
```

I can create the vector `x` and `i` which will be the equivalent of `SMatrix@x` and `SMatrix@i` like this:

```
x <- rep(1, nrow(positions))
i <- positions[order(positions[,2]),1] - 1
```

But how can I create the vector `p`, which should be the equivalent of `SMatrix@p` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Matrix::sparseMatrix` to get the compressed, or pointer representation of the row or column indices.

```
Matrix::sparseMatrix(positions[,1], positions[,2], x=1)@p
#[1] 0 2 2 3
```

or use `diffinv` like:

```
diffinv(c(table(factor(positions[,2], seq_len(max(positions[,2]))))))
#[1] 0 2 2 3
```

Doing the opposite of:

```
dp <- diff(p)
rep(seq_along(dp),dp)
```

What is given in the manual to expanded form `p` to row or column indices.

Comment: Great, I was trying to avoid creating the entire Matrix like in your first option, but the second one does exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot!

Comment: You know that `i` is created different than in your question? It should be something like: `positions[order(positions[,2]),1] - 1`.

Comment: Yes, you are absoluteley right. I'll modify my comment.

Comment: If the sparse matrix has its last column with all zero entries, then your formula doesn't take in account those columns.

Comment: In case the last column has only zero entries, it should not be taken into account (should not have an index) in a spares matrix.